# Calculating the average of 5 test scores Java

Tags: java

I have code that asks the user to input 5 test scores and then it calculates the average of the 5 test scores. The code compiles and runs just fine,but my question is: My code outputs more dialog boxes than necessary. I would like to try to find a way to display the output all at once or with fewer dialog boxes. I am new to Java so I am still learning. If you run the code, you will have a better understanding of what I am trying to get across.

Update: By any chance, does anyone know why the Grade 0.0 is appearing in my results window? What would be the best way to get rid of that?

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //Needed for GUI

import java.text.DecimalFormat; //needed to format the Output





public class DTTestAverageAndGrade

{//Begin class

public static void main(String[] args)

{//Begin main method



    String inputString;   //For reader's input

    double Score1,       //Define score1

           Score2,      //Define  score2

           Score3,     //Define   score3

           Score4,    //Define    score4
           Score5,   //Define     score5
           Average ;//Define      Average



DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0"); //format the scores



    // Get the five scores

    inputString=

      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the First Test Score: "); //ask user to enter the first test score

    Score1 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



    inputString=

      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Second Test Score: ");//ask user to enter the second test score

    Score2 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



    inputString=

      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the third test score: ");//ask user to enter the third test score

    Score3 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



    inputString=

      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the fourth test score: ");//ask user to enter the fourth test score

    Score4 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



    inputString=

      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the fifth test score: ");//ask user to enter the fifth test score

    Score5 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



    // Call to method calcAverage and output the 5 test average

      Average = calcAverage(Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5);







    // Display Average test Score and Determine the letter grade for each test and call to determineGrade



            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\nYour Score 1  is : " +formatter.format(Score1)  +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Score1)

                                              + "\t\nYour Score 2  is : " +formatter.format(Score2)  +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Score2)

                                              + "\t\nYour Score 3  is : " +formatter.format(Score3)  +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Score3)

                                              + "\t\nYour Score 4  is : " +formatter.format(Score4)  +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Score4)

                                              + "\t\nYour Score 5  is : " +formatter.format(Score5)  +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Score5)

                                           + "\t\nYour Average  is : " +formatter.format(Average) +"\t Grade: " + determineGrade(Average),

                                                "\tYour Test Results",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



    }//end Main method



    // Calculate the average of the five test scores

    public static double calcAverage(double Score1, double Score2, double Score3, double Score4, double Score5)

    {

        double Average = ((Score1 + Score2 + Score3 + Score4 + Score5) / 5);

        return Average;

    }



    // Determine the letter grade for the average and 5 test scores

   public static double determineGrade(double Average)

    {

        char grade; // Define grade



        // Determine letter grade

     if (Average>=90)

        {

            grade = 'A';

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grade + "\n");

     }

        else if (Average>=80)

        {

            grade = 'B';

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grade + "\n");

        }

        else if (Average>=70)

        {

            grade = 'C';

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grade + "\n");

        }

        else if (Average>=60)

        {

            grade = 'D';

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grade + "\n");

        }

        else if (Average<60)

        {

            grade = 'F';

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grade + "\n");

      }

        else

        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error\n");

        }



        return 0;



    }//end determinegrade method

}//end class
```

Comment: Instead of asking the user to input a string in five separate dialog boxes, have them enter all five into a single dialog box separated by spaces or commas. Then split your string on commas or white space.

Comment: @eestrada: same idea with me :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer(s)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put almost anything in the `Object` parameter of `showInputDialog`. Most likely you'll want to add a panel with whatever bits you need in it for example:

```
  JTextField score1 = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField score2 = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField score3 = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField score4 = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField score5 = new JTextField(10);

  JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
  scorePanel.add(new JLabel("First Test Score:"));
  scorePanel.add(score1);
  scorePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
  scorePanel.add(new JLabel("Second Test Score:"));
  scorePanel.add(score2);
  scorePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
  scorePanel.add(new JLabel("Third Test Score:"));
  scorePanel.add(score3);
  scorePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
  scorePanel.add(new JLabel("Fourth Test Score:"));
  scorePanel.add(score4);
  scorePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
  scorePanel.add(new JLabel("Fifth Test Score:"));
  scorePanel.add(score5);

  int result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, scorePanel, 
           "Please enter all 5 test scores.");

  double Score1 = Double.parseDouble(score1.getText());
  double Score2 = Double.parseDouble(score2.getText());
  ... etc.
```

Then calculate and show the result like you do already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will play around with that now to better understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can input one string and split out.
For example:

```
String inputString=
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 test Scores with comma: "); //ask user to enter the 5 test scores at once

 String[] scores = inputString.split(",");
score1 = scores[0];
score2 = scores[1];
score3 = scores[2];
score4 = scores[3];
score5 = scores[4];
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot!